# Need to get relatives data not empty in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have some models for which I redefined method **find()** for my own ActiveQuery.
For example

```
public static function find(){
    return new scopes\SomeModelQuery(get_called_class());
}
```

I do it cause I need to get i18n data from database. Like this

```
Model::find()
       ->withI18n()
       ->all();
```

But sometimes relatives data can be empty, and then when i appeal it returning error page because it's null (not object). 
Of course I know it's normal, but I dont want to get null if relatives data not found, in this case I want to get the model object with empty properties.

Is there any method to reach that?

Comment: On what line the error shows up?

Comment: What does your `withI18n()` method do? We are going to need to see what is inside `SomeModelQuery`.